# Is it possible to edit the OpenAI Universe starter-agent on different (custom) OpenAI gym environments?

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

The starter agent is provided with a MD that provides an example for atari pong and flashdrive using openAI gym environments. Is it possible to edit the envs.py file (and/or possibly others) of the starter agent so that it can work for other (e.g. custom) gym environments as well, or is the agent in its entirety only adapted for these specific games? Are there any requirements the env should satisfy?